# Angularjs ng-model inside ng-repeat via (key,val) not updating

Tags: angularjs

Here is my not working [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/qMxUY3AhwDgI4P9lcGW8?p=preview)

```
<section ng-repeat="t in test">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in t">
    <div>{{key}}</div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="value"/>
  </div>
</section>
```

Model stays the same. How to sync? Please note, structure of data is important.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The `ng-model` binding will evaluate its expression on the current scope. As `ng-repeat` creates a child scope, this means that `ng-model` will look for a property named `value` on the child scope. In your example we'd expect it to look for the `val` property on the **parent** scope, which is aliased to `t`.

This is by design and can be circumvented in your case by referencing the parent scope `t` in the expression.

[Working demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/Liq5ljY6Si5Ye61z1xEM?p=preview)

Code (notice the binding on the input element has changed):

```
<section ng-repeat="t in test">
  <div ng-repeat="(key,value) in t">
    <div>{{key}}</div>
   <input type="text" ng-model="t[key]"/>
  </div>
</section>
```

As you're using a beta version of Angular 1.3, this may be a bug.

Comment: If there is no '.' in ng-model, then when the model is assigned on scope (i.e. text is entered in the input field), it will create a shadow variable in the child scope (ng-repeat creates the child scope) that is a copy of the variable in parent scope - breaking two-way binding. This is by design - but can be the source of a lot of confusion. array notation (item[]) is the exception.

Comment: so what if ng-model is not the value `t[key]` but the key itself? What would be the syntax to reference the key as the model value?

Comment: @ahnbizcad not tested, but I assume `ng-model="key"`. If this doesn't work, you may need to first create an array of keys using something like `Object.keys`