# A bug in a JSON editor by AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I want to use [this JSON editor](http://mb21.github.io/JSONedit/), but I have found a bug: JUST after loading the web page, if we modify a value of a field in the treeview (resp., textarea), the value in the textarea (resp., treeview) will change automatically, which is great. However, after loading the web page, if we modify first a value in the treeview (eg, `Miller` to `Miller 1`), then modify the value of the SAME field in the textarea (eg, `Miller 1` to `Miller 2`), the value in the treeview will NOT be changed automatically (ie, it is still `Miller 1`).

I tried to make a shorter [JSBin](https://jsbin.com/yafidozaja/2/edit?html,output), which has the same bug. 
I think the bug probably comes from the AngularJS part:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="JSONedit">
<head>

  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mb21/JSONedit/gh-pages/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mb21/JSONedit/gh-pages/bower_components/jquery-ui/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mb21/JSONedit/gh-pages/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mb21/JSONedit/gh-pages/bower_components/angular-ui-sortable/sortable.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/mb21/JSONedit/gh-pages/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <link href="https://rawgit.com/mb21/JSONedit/gh-pages/css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

  <script src="https://rawgit.com/mb21/JSONedit/gh-pages/js/directives.js"></script>
</head>
<body>  
  <script>
    'use strict';

    var app = angular.module('exampleApp', ['JSONedit']);

    function MainViewCtrl($scope, $filter) {
        $scope.jsonData = { Name: "Joe" };

        $scope.$watch('jsonData', function(json) {
            $scope.jsonString = $filter('json')(json);
        }, true);
        $scope.$watch('jsonString', function(json) {
            try {
                $scope.jsonData = JSON.parse(json);
                $scope.wellFormed = true;
            } catch(e) {
                $scope.wellFormed = false;
            }
        }, true);
    }
  </script>
  <div id="mainView" ng-controller="MainViewCtrl">
    <div class="jsonView">
      <json child="jsonData" default-collapsed="false" type="object"></json>
    </div>

    <hr>
    <div>
      <textarea id="jsonTextarea" ng-model="jsonString"></textarea>
      <span class="red" ng-if="!wellFormed">JSON not well-formed!</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know what's wrong there?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a JSONedit bug, just submitted a [merge request](https://github.com/mb21/JSONedit/pull/46).

Reason is that "child" binding updates may not propagate to ng-repeat.
Using parent scope reference fixes this (simpler example here [Angularjs ng-model inside ng-repeat via (key,val) not updating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774435/angularjs-ng-model-inside-ng-repeat-via-key-val-not-updating))

Relevant code:

```
<span ng-repeat="(key, val) in child">
  ...
  <input type="text" ng-model="child[key]"
```

As a temporary fix, you may embed the whole script to your page, working example [here](http://jsbin.com/sepedefaku/2/edit?html,output)

Comment: do you have any idea about [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41507024/add-a-table-type-to-a-json-editor)?