# Adding the input fields dynamically from nested json object in angulajs

Tags: angularjs, arrays, json

```
 var inputs={
    'firstname': '',
    'lastName':'',
   'account':{
     'role':'',
     'status':''
   }
 }
```

This is my model array. I want to display it dynamically in Webpage and by modifying the json array the changes should affect the form too.

Here is the image
[image]

Comment: use $scope or angular model {{model}}

Comment: Can you please share the code for this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in myPersonObj">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in value1">
        <label>{{key}}</label>
        <input type="text" name="" value="{{value}}">
    </div>
</div>
```

```
var app = angular.module("test",[]);

app.controller("MainCtrl",function($scope){

  $scope.inputs = [
    {
      "firstname" : "Test"
    },{
      "lastname" : "Test1"
    },{                           
      "Account" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account1" : [

        {"role" : "Test3"},
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    },
    {
      "Account2" : [

        {"role" : {
          'dim3': {
            'dim4':{
              'dim5':'cccc'
            }
          }
        }

      },
        {"status" : "Test4"},
      ]
    }
  ];
$scope.person = [];
$scope.myPersonObj = [];
/*console.log($scope.keys(inputs));*/
    $scope.checkIndex1 = function(arg, myPersonObj)
    {
        if (angular.isArray(arg) || angular.isObject(arg)) {
            angular.forEach(arg, function (value, key) {
                console.log(value);
                if(angular.isObject(value) || angular.isArray(value))
                {
                    $scope.checkIndex1(value, myPersonObj);
                }
                else
                {
                    console.log("pushing");
                    myPersonObj.push(arg);
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {
            console.log("pushing1");
            myPersonObj.push(arg);
        }      
    }

    $scope.checkIndex1($scope.inputs, $scope.myPersonObj);

    console.log("myPersonObj :"+ JSON.stringify($scope.myPersonObj));

    console.log($scope.inputs);
```

Comment: @Pengyy : please have a look at it and give me suggestions

Comment: @Rohit : please have a look at it this is the way i wanted

Answer (score 1):

**UPD:**
for your situation, you can use `ng-switch` to generate elements according to conditions.

---

**Notice**(already included in the code snippet):
ng-repeat will generate it's own `scope`, so your model won't update unless you bind it with the `original scope`. ref [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24774435/angularjs-ng-model-inside-ng-repeat-via-key-val-not-updating).

---

**OLD ANSWER:**
use `ng-model` to implement `two-way-databinding`. 
refer the code snippet below:

```js
angular.module("app", []).controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.inputs = {
    'firstname': 'test first name',
    'lastName': 'test last name',
    'account': {
      'role': 'test role',
      'status': 'test status'
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.4/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="myCtrl">
  <!-- First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.firstname"><br>     
       Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.lastName"><br>        Account Role: <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.account.role"><br> 
       Account Status: <input type="text" ng-model="inputs.account.status"><br> -->
  <div ng-repeat="(key1, value) in inputs" ng-switch="key1">
    <div ng-switch-when="account">
      <div ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value">
        {{key1 | uppercase}} => {{ key2 | uppercase}}
        <input type="text" ng-model="inputs[key1][key2]">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div ng-switch-default>
      {{key1 | uppercase}}
      <input type="text" ng-model="inputs[key1]">
    </div>
  </div>
  {{inputs}}
</div>
```

Comment: it should not be like this ...see the array contains inner arrays and i cannot use the input fields here it should be created automatically from the json array model

Comment: <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in inputs" >
        <div  ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value">
            <label>{{key1}}</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="{{value1}}">

Comment: @DeepakVijay do you mean the `object` contains inner `object`?

Comment: yes the object contains inner object and its a nested json array..it should check each time array values.. and if it is an inner array it should print it..and we should not use the code each time to create input fields

Comment: yes the object contains inner object and its a nested json array..it should check each time array values.. and if it is an inner array it should print it..and we should not use the code each time to create input fields

Comment: @DeepakVijay Please update your question and post the nested json array which you are using. Also add a fiddle or plunkr if possible

Comment: @Pengyy :- this code only works when i use this json array ..what if i have some dynamic array ? in which fields can be modified all the time (Add or Remove)..i need the solution for that

Comment: @Nishant123 :- i did posted the nested array format that i'm using ..i need my form fields should dynamically made from  the json array

Comment: @DeepakVijay I think this have answered specifically what you have asked. Please mark this as an answer and make a new question if you have other problem and I will be glad to offer some help there.

Answer (score 0):

/*My html should look like this*/

```
  <head>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.1" data-semver="1.4.1" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.1/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">


    <script type="text/ng-template" id="tree-structure">
    <label>{{dt}}</label><input type="text" name="" value="{{dt.label}}">
     <ul class="childElement">
        <li ng-repeat="dt in dt.nodes" ng-include="'tree-structure'">
        </li>
     </ul>
</script>

<ul class="parentList">
    <li ng-repeat="(key, value) in inputs" >
        <div  ng-repeat="(key1, value1) in value">
            <label>{{key1}}</label>
            <input type="text" name="" value="{{value1}}">

           <!--  <div ng-repeat="(key2, value2) in value1">
              <label>{{key2}}</label><input type="text" name="" value="{{value2}}"> 
            </div> -->

        </div>
        <div ></div>
    </li>

    </div>
</ul>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: you should add details to your question, not by answering here.

Answer (score 0):

**Some observations :**

- Your `JSON` should be formatted properly with `type` of the field.
- If you want to access the `object properties` as a `form fields` then it should be structured in a good way so that we can dynamically add the type of the field as well.

  ```
  [{
      name: 'firstName',
      type: 'text'
  }, {
      name: 'lastname',
      type: 'text'
  }, {
      account: [{
          name: 'role',
          type: 'text'
      }, {
          name: 'status',
          type: 'text'
      }]
  }]
  ```
- As your `JSON` have `nested objects`. So, first iterate it recursively and create `one dimensional` array then create the fields using `1D` array.

**DEMO**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    var inputs = [{
 name: 'firstName',
 type: 'text'
}, {
 name: 'lastname',
 type: 'text'
}, {
 account: [{
  name: 'role',
  type: 'text'
 }, {
  name: 'status',
  type: 'text'
 }]
}];

$scope.fields = [];
function structuredObj(obj) {
  for (var i in obj) {
     if (obj[i].type == 'text') {
       $scope.fields.push(obj[i]);
     } else {
       structuredObj(obj[i])
     }
  }
};

structuredObj(inputs);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
<form name="myForm" novalidate>
  <div ng-repeat="item in fields" class="form-group">
        <input
            name="item.name"
            type="{{ item.type }}"
            placeholder="{{ item.name }}"
            ng-model="item.value"
            required />
  </div>
<button ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid">Submit</button>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: you used 2 ng-repeats ..this will work upto 2-dimension ..what if in the case of 3D and 4d and more than that..i need solution for that..i want solution for any number of fields that can be made dynamically from any json array (nested Json)

Comment: @DeepakVijay I updated the answer. you can check now.

Comment: :- please provide the answer in the format please . i need labels to be added and sub array should be shown as sub array with arrows..

Comment: This small thing you can do yourself also. I can not give everything on your plate.